# How to read content from a *.wiq file with C#

Tags: c#, file, import, tfs-2015, wiql

As the title says i want to read all text from a .wiq file as a String in C#.
Is it possible somehow? Because the normal StreamReader only works for .txt!

Comment: A Work Item Query file is an XML file. Just read the text of the nodes you're interested in.

Comment: i tried to load the .wiq file as XML file, but that has not worked for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
using( System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\temp\queryName.wiq") )
{
    string allLines = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```